# How do I hide the authoring information?

Tags: nodes, 8

I installed Drupal 8.2.4 and the IceMagic-8.x-1.0 theme. 
How do I hide the authoring information on articles?

Answer (score 4):

Edit the node type, in the "Display settings", there is a checkbox "Display author and date information", turn that off.

Comment: In      Home > Administration > Structure > Content types > Display Settings  (Display author and date information), I've had already turned it off, but the author and date still show. Even after clearing the cache.

Comment: By the way, ther is an option to make the images responsive in      Home > Administration > Appearance >Appearance settings > (Ice Magic) > Images > Responsive Images, that doesn't work either. I had to edit the styles.css and add  "img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }". Did you tried it with IceMagic?

Comment: No, not field display settings. *Edit* the node type, then in the vertical tab.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I did. The URL is http://MY_SITE/admin/structure/types/manage/article, then in the vertical tab I chose "Display Settings" and unchecked "Display author and date information". But the author info and date still shows on articles.
I am working with a multisite solution, with only one core Drupal installation. I edited sites.php, created 2 folders, etc., and disabled authoring info on both sites, but it doesn't work on either site.
Can it be a bug of the IceMagic theme?

Comment: Could be, yes. check its node.html.twig template and compare it to the default in the classy theme.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is exactly in that file, on the mbase theme.
It's not a bug, it's a different behavior based on different variables.
I edited it and solved the problem.