# Can I change the Display Settings by modifying the database?

Tags: 8, database

I am using Drupal 8.5.6 and need to make the authoring information hidden for each content type. In other words, there should be no 'authored by admin on (date)' on any page. The fix should be simple ([How do I hide the authoring information?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224318/how-do-i-hide-the-authoring-information)) but similarly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771776/drupal-8-display-settings-tab-missing-from-all-content-types, I do not have the display settings tab. I can get it back by uninstalling the Manage Display module (I tested on a seperate site), but there is a module dependent on 'Manage Display', which if I uninstall, content that shows up on the main page is lost.

Is there a way to replicate checking the 'Display author and date information' box from the database alone? Or is there a way to change this setting without uninstalling the Manage Display Module?

Comment: You mean this https://www.drupal.org/project/manage_display? What an unlucky name for a module. Why do you want to uninstall it? You can also hide these infos with your own templates or some preprocessing.

Comment: I don't want to uninstall it, but the module gets rid of the 'manage display' tab, which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the config and change in node.type.[content-type].yml:

```
display_submitted: false
```

and import the config again or edit the live config directly with Drush, for example of the content type Article:

```
drush cedit node.type.article
```

Comment: 'drush cedit node.type.[node type]' worked like a charm! Simple and easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to NOT display the author information on the page? If so edit the content type. Go to Display settings > Display author and date information
Author username and publish date will be displayed. 
Mark the box unchecked.
From now on any new content will not contain the author information.

You will have to edit all previous content prior to setting this unchecked to not display the author and date information.