# How do I set the default values for creating a new content type?

Tags: 8, nodes

This is a follow up to my question in [Can I change the Display Settings by modifying the database?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/270238/can-i-change-the-display-settings-by-modifying-the-database) which was answered. Basically, I could not get to the 'display authoring and date information' checkbox because of a module installed. Running the command 'drush cedit node.type.article' as given in @4k4's answer allows me to change this setting.

However, when a new content type is created, the type has `display_submitted: true` set meaning I have to go in and change it whenever a new content type is created, which I sometimes cannot do.

Is there a way to change the default settings so that any new content type has `display_submitted: false` by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For content or config entities you can set default values in a hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create():

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create() for 'node_type'.
 */
function mymodule_node_type_create(NodeType $node_type) {
  $node_type->set('display_submitted', FALSE);
}
```

Comment: So do I still have to do this for every new content type? If not, where exactly do I use this code?

Comment: No, once this hook is implemented it is called automatically when new content types are created. Put it in the file `mymodule.module` of a custom module, replace mymodule with your module name.

Comment: That does the trick! I didn't realize I had two write a module to do this (it might be a good idea to mention that in your answer, although people more familiar with drupal than me would already know that).